# Select only one checkbox in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have few check boxes in different table rows with same class name. I want only one should be selected among them at a time. I am trying something like following but nothing working,

```
$('.sev_check').click(function() {

                $('.sev_check').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

or,

```
$('.sev_check').click(function() {
    $cur=$(this).prop('checked');
    $(".sev_check").each(function(){ 
       $(this).prop('checked',false);
    })
    $(this).prop('checked', $cur);  
});
```

Here are how my checkboxes are aligned,

[image]

HTML,

```
<div class="checkbox text-center">
    <label class="form-checkbox form-icon">
        <input id="s_fac" type="checkbox" class="sev_check">
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Should they be radio buttons? "A radio button or option button is a graphical control element that allows the user to choose only one of a predefined set of options." - Wikipedia

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need radio buttons.

Comment: Radio buttons are exactly what you need. If you're so hung up on style, style the radio buttons like a checkbox

Comment: From your description of what you want to happen, they are *exactly* what you need.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle.net

Comment: I could do the all styling if I really want to use radio button but I don't need. I know it's easy to do using radio. But that's not what I am looking for. It should be fairly easy to do even with checkboxes.

Comment: once a check box is clicked, disable all other boxes so there is no option to select any other.

Comment: @RavinderReddy : but in that case, the user cannot change his choice, he'll be stuck with the checkbox that he chooses first since the others have been disabled and will not respond to mouse events now.

Answer (score 9):

You approach works fine, try the fiddle

```
$('.sev_check').click(function() {
    $('.sev_check').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Here's a fiddle showing it working: https://jsfiddle.net/ruidfigueiredo/h3kfj2n9/2/

Comment: @Rishi Try the jsfiddle, it works exactly as you intend.

Comment: Rui, I really appreciate it but still same code not working for me :( May be bootstrap design making things complex.

Comment: @Rishi I've updated the fiddle so that it uses bootstrap for styling. Have you checked if there are any javascript (somewhere else in your file) that may be causing the click hander not to run (you can just open the website on chrome, press F12, select Console tab and reload the page, any errors will show up there)

Comment: @Rui

Thanks. Good Solution.

Answer (score 5):

Your first approach works for me like you can see in the snippet, but you can
use a different approach like:

```
$(function () {
   $('.sev_check').change(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('.sev_check').not(this).prop('checked', false);
       $(this).prop('checked', true);
   });
});
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('.sev_check').click(function(e) {
    $('.sev_check').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="checkbox text-center">
            <label class="form-checkbox form-icon" for="s_fac">
                <input id="s_fac" type="checkbox" class="sev_check">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox text-center">
            <label class="form-checkbox form-icon" for="s_fac1">
                <input id="s_fac1" type="checkbox" class="sev_check">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox text-center">
            <label class="form-checkbox form-icon" for="s_fac2">
                <input id="s_fac2" type="checkbox" class="sev_check">
            </label>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Still not working :( I am guessing due to my checkboxes are in table rows.. Going to modify your fiddle to test this theory.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT :**
Start with all the checkboxes looking like they're disabled, once a checkbox is selected, it appears selected while the others appear disabled, when another checkbox is clicked that one appears selected while the others appear disabled using opacity values for the input elements.

---

**Check my snippet below:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sev_check').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('unselected');
  });
  $('.sev_check').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('unselected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $('.sev_check').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    $('.sev_check').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $('.sev_check').not(this).addClass('unselected');
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  opacity: 1
}
.unselected {
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox text-center">
  <table border="2">
    <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>
        <input id="s_fac" type="checkbox" class="sev_check">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td>
        <input id="s_fac" type="checkbox" class="sev_check">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 3</td>
      <td>
        <input id="s_fac" type="checkbox" class="sev_check">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 4</td>
      <td>
        <input id="s_fac" type="checkbox" class="sev_check">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 5</td>
      <td>
        <input id="s_fac" type="checkbox" class="sev_check">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working perfectly but you need one extra step to un-check in order to select new one. Hate to say but my user going to surely object :(

Comment: @Rishi
So then if you want to change your choice, you directly want to select it without unchecking  the previous choice ?

Comment: @Rishi : check my updated snippet , you can make all the checkboxes look disabled except the one that has been selected using toggleClass, the extra step to uncheck the previous checkbox is not required now.